# Databases: Migrate data between MS Access DB and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, data-migration

I have 2 databases, one is MS Access DB from an old website, and the other one is MYSQL from the new Joomla+VirtueMart based website.
I need to migrate existing products from MS Access to MYSQL.

I thought of putting both on server and writing SQL queries in MYSQL workbench, untill I have a good script for that, but I'm very new to SQL, so I'd rather avoid that.

I there a better way and more efficient for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always [export](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/d5432b8e-08f6-4b6a-b13d-fc7656970704) to CSV and [import](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) that in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

you can use tools like [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a free graphical tool called "MySQL Migration toolkit" which automates the migration of Access 2003 MDB files (schema + data) into MySQL.
More info at the following link:

http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/a-guide-for-migrating-from-microsoft-access-to-mysql/

(you need to register with Oracle to download the PDF guide).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another link using the ODBC technology

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html